# Performing Multiple Averages in an SQL query on the same column

Tags: sqlite

So for some context, I have a database that has a Listings table with the following attributes: id, name, neighborhood_id, price, roomType_id.

I also have a Neighborhoods table that just has two attributes: id, name.

Lastly, I have a RoomTypes table with two attributes: id, roomType.

Now I want to run a query that queries the Listings table and returns the price difference between private rooms (aka roomType_id == 1) and entire homes/apartments (aka roomType_id == 2) in each neighborhood (which would be a group by of Listings.neighborhood_id). My problem is figuring out how to essentially run the following query two times in a single query and take the difference between the two columns to make a third new column. Ideally, I'd also like there to be a fourth column that lists the name of the neighborhood that this difference applies to.

Version 1 of the Query

```
SELECT n.name as "Neighborhood Name", AVG(l.price) as "Private Room Price"
FROM Listings l
INNER JOIN Neighborhoods n on l.neighborhood_id = n.id
INNER JOIN RoomTypes r on l.roomType_id = r.id
WHERE r.roomType = "Private room"
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Version 2 of the Query

```
SELECT n.name as "Neighborhood Name", AVG(l.price) as "Entire home/apt Price"
FROM Listings l
INNER JOIN Neighborhoods n on l.neighborhood_id = n.id
INNER JOIN RoomTypes r on l.roomType_id = r.id
WHERE r.roomType = "Entire home/apt"
GROUP BY n.id;
```

I also tried this kind of query to no avail...

```
SELECT n.name as "Neighborhood Name", AVG(l.price) as "Private Room Price", AVG(l2.price) as "Entire home/apt Price"
FROM Listings l
INNER JOIN Listings l2 on l.id = l2.id
INNER JOIN Neighborhoods n on l.neighborhood_id = n.id
INNER JOIN RoomTypes r on l.roomType_id = r.id
INNER JOIN RoomTypes r2 on l2.roomType_id = r2.id
WHERE r2.roomType = "Entire home/apt" AND r.roomType = "Private room"
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I used the CASE keyword...

```
SELECT n.name as "Neighborhood Name",
    AVG(CASE WHEN r.roomType = "Private room" THEN l.price ELSE NULL END) as "Private Room Price",
    AVG(CASE WHEN r.roomType = "Entire home/apt" THEN l.price ELSE NULL END) as "Entire home/apt Price",
    AVG(CASE WHEN r.roomType = "Entire home/apt" THEN l.price ELSE NULL END) - AVG(CASE WHEN r.roomType = "Private room" THEN l.price ELSE NULL END) as "Price Difference"
FROM Listings l
INNER JOIN Neighborhoods n on l.neighborhood_id = n.id
INNER JOIN RoomTypes r on l.roomType_id = r.id
GROUP BY n.id;
```